# "Under construction" pages and multiple canonicalization tags

Tags: seo, html, canonical-url

My website has a few pages that are still "under construction" and I want to go online.

What is the best practice to redirect all `HREF` links to a common "under construction" page?

Can it be done using canonicalization by including multiple `link=rel` tags inside the `head` of the under construction page for all the incomplete pages or are there any simpler methods?

Comment: Don't use "under construction" pages, period.   Every site could use some improvement and most webmasters have new pages planned.     Users hate seeing "under construction."   It causes them to leave in droves.   Don't link to anything before it is actually built.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solutions:

1. Don't add (or hide) the navigation links to those pages.
2. Add a simple redirect method in your header so that the link sends you to the home/splash or another page.

   ```
   <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/" />
   ```
3. FTP your site so that it's "in place online", but password protect it so that you can see it online while you finish working on it. On an Apache server you would use [.htaccess](http://www.htaccess-guide.com/) and [.htpasswd](http://www.htaccess-guide.com/password-protection/) files to accomplish this.
4. Finish those pages before you go public.

I understand that you are excited about getting your website online, but having the "under construction" pages is going to keep people away instead of bringing more people in. Your page content is what gets people to "stick around" and if there isn't anything there.... there isn't a reason for them to be there either. Don't misunderstand me, no website is ever really done. You want to be constantly adding and editing to improve what you have. This is what brings people in. But, you should avoid having them land on a page that's empty.

Comment: But what if in case i have a page under update for 2 or 3 days?

Comment: Any of the options will continue working until  you change them. So, if you want to use #2, the redirect, it will continue redirecting the pages until you load a page that doesn't include the meta tag that redirects it to another page.  If you use #1, and hide the links, the links will remain hidden until you make the links visible. Does that make sense?